# Firebase Callable function with JWT Authentication and Google Sheets V4 API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I want to implement firebase callable function with JWT Authentication and fetching data from Google Sheet, using Google Sheets V4 API.
For test I tried to use [Example Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit#gid=0) but Sheets API not activated for that Spreadsheet and I cloned it on my own drive and use it for testing.

**References:**
My code based on solution described in this question [How to use Google sheets API while inside a google cloud function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44448029/how-to-use-google-sheets-api-while-inside-a-google-cloud-function) and [Accessing Google APIs using Service account in Node.JS](http://isd-soft.com/tech_blog/accessing-google-apis-using-service-account-node-js/)

Also I have got two important information: **"Service Account".json** and **API Key**. I save API Key in api_key.json but didn't find examples how to use it with Google Sheets V4 API:

```
{ 
  key: "xxxxxx"
}
```

test() callable function which doesn't require any authentication works fine:

```
exports.test = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return { text: data.text };
});
```

Calling test() function somewhere on client (in Browser):

```
function getTest() {
  console.log("clicked getTest()");
  var test = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('test');

  test({text: '12345'}).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}
```

Calling getData() somewhere on client (in Browser):

```
function requestData() {
  console.log("clicked requestData()");

  //https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable
  //getData() function described in functions/index.js

  var getData = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('getData');

  getData(null).then(function (result) {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
    console.log(result);  //<------- Expected rows from Spreadsheet????
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
  });
}
```

**Thank you, F10. I corrected code. 
index.js:

```
'use strict'
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { google } = require('googleapis');
var serviceAccount = require("./credentials/owner-service-account-gcloud.json");

function getJwt() {
  // Define the required scopes.
  var scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets'
  ];
  return new google.auth.JWT(
    serviceAccount.client_email,
    null,
    serviceAccount.private_key,
    scopes
  );
}

function getSpreadsheetDate(jwt) {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.authorize((error, access_token) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log('Error in jwt.authorize: ' + error);
        reject(error);
      } else {
        // access_token ready to use to fetch data and return to client
        const sheets = google.sheets({ version: 'v4', access_token });

        // set auth as a global default:
        google.options({ auth: jwt }); //<---------------------- 

        const request = {
          auth: jwt,
          spreadsheetId: 'xxxx',
          range: 'Class Data!A2:E', //'Class Data!A2:E',
        }

        sheets.spreadsheets.values.get(request, (err, response) => {
          console.log("inside: sheets.spreadsheets.values.get() -------------------------------");

          if (err) {
            console.log('The Sheets API returned an error: ' + err);
            //The API returned an error: Error: API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.
            reject(err);
          };

          try {
            var numRows = response.data.values ? response.data.values.length : 0;
            console.log('%d rows retrieved.', numRows);

            console.log("response.data:-------------------------------");
            console.log(response.data.values);

            resolve(response.data.values);

          } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error processing Sheets API response: " + err);
            reject(err);
          }

        })

      }
    })
  })

}


exports.getData = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  console.log("getData()---------------------------");
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('failed-precondition', 'The function must be called ' + 'while authenticated.');
  } else {
    console.log("context.auth ------------ OK");
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    console.log(uid);

    var jwt = getJwt();
    console.log("getJwt() --------------- OK");

    return getSpreadsheetDate(jwt); //<------------ Requested Spreadsheet's Data

  }
})

exports.test = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return { text: data.text };
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48290167) that uses `googleapis` instead of the auth library to do the authentication with JWT. Regarding your token inquiries, you could check the [OAuth 2.0 for client-side web applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#top_of_page) documentations, which explains the steps to do the authentication.